# How to get a rating average in Mongoose / node (With rating in array of objects)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need to calculate the rating average of an article, and the rating are in an array of objects

Here is my schema / model:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Article', {
    title : String,
    text : String,
    star : { type: Number, default: 3.5}
    ...
});

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     email        : String,
     password     : String,
     name         : String,
     rating       : {type : Array, default: []}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

where object in rating array are like `{ "rate" : "X", "articleID" : "Y" }`

Now in this function i need to calculate the rating average

```
function recalculateArticleRate(articleIDD) {
    console.log("Recalculate article rate");
    User.aggregate([
        { $match: { "rating.articleID" : articleIDD } },
        { $unwind: "$rating" },
        { $group : {_id : "$_id", avgRate : {  $avg : "$rating.rate" } } }
    ], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(result);
    });
}
```

This is the result object:

```
[ { _id: 58f519acfcb29003b572048b, avgRate: 3 },
{ _id: 58f5093159c45002f10ea7da, avgRate: 3 } ]
```

Doing this I get the average of all users evalutation, but i want the average of the rating of all users when rating.articleID = articleIDD.
How I can do that with Mongoose?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB - calculating average of nested array of objects' attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159487/mongodb-calculating-average-of-nested-array-of-objects-attributes)

Comment: Replace your group stage with `{ $group : {_id : null, avgRate : {  $avg : "$rating.rate" } } }`

Answer (score 0):

```
function recalculateArticleRate(articleIDD) {
    User.aggregate([
        { $unwind: "$rating" },
        { $match: { "rating.articleID" : articleIDD } },
        { $group : {_id : null, avgRate : {  $avg : "$rating.rate" } } }
    ], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

Put unwind before and _id = null (as recommended by Veeram) solved my problem !